# Node.js Module.Exports Undefined Empty Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, circular-dependency

I have the following files.

**index.js**

```
module.exports = {
    "first": require('./1.js'),
    "second": require('./2.js'),
    "third": require('./3.js')
};
```

**1.js**

```
module.exports = "Hello";
```

**2.js**

```
module.exports = "World";
```

**3.js**

```
const utils = require('./');
module.exports = `${utils.first} ${utils.second}`;
```

**run.js**

```
const utils = require('./');
console.log(utils.first);
console.log(utils.second);
console.log(utils.third);
```

Why is it that when I run `node run.js` that it prints the following?

```
Hello
World
undefined undefined
```

I expect it to print

```
Hello
World
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because at the time of running `3.js` the `index.js` file has not been fully defined yet. In order to fix this you have to require the files specifically. For example changing `3.js` to the following will work.

```
const first = require('./1.js');
const second = require('./2.js');
module.exports = `${first} ${second}`;
```

Comment: just curious: Is this is how circular dependencies are resolved ? Like with an undefined. By circular dep I mean `index`>`3`>`index` in the question.

Comment: I think so, yeah. I just ran into a circular dependency type thing. I didn't know it was called that, but yes that sounds like the correct term. This was how I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line:

```
   "third": require('./3.js')
```

You cannot make `index.js` dependend on `3.js` as `3.js` is dependend on `index.js` (thats called circular dependency). Nodejs might be able to resolve it some specific cases but I woupd generally not do this. Instead extract the parts that `3.js` uses from `index.js` into a new file, and then import that from both.